# gson fromjson throws NoClassDefFound error when deserializing custom object

Tags: android, json, gson

I am attempting something really simple and it should just work:

Can anyone comment why I am able to serialize json but not able to deserialize it back and get my object back.

Classes

```
public class ConfigJsonObj {
public List<ConfigJson_InvitesPending> invites_pending;

public ConfigJsonObj() {
    invites_pending = new ArrayList<ConfigJson_InvitesPending>();
}

public ConfigJsonObj(List<ConfigJson_InvitesPending> invitesPendings) {
    invites_pending = new ArrayList<ConfigJson_InvitesPending>();
    if (invitesPendings!=null) {
        invites_pending.addAll( invitesPendings);
    }
} 
}

public class ConfigJson_InvitesPending {
public String toDisplayName;

public ConfigJson_InvitesPending() {}

public ConfigJson_InvitesPending(String toName) {
    toDisplayName = toName;
}
}
```

Code to serialize

```
String json = gson.toJson(configJsonObjObject);
```

Json generated

```
{
 "invites_pending": [
 {
   "toDisplayName": "London"
 }
 ]
}
```

Code to deserialize

```
ConfigJsonObj obj = gson.fromJson(json, ConfigJsonObj.class);
    return obj;
```

Exception when I call gson.fromJson(...) above :

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
 more.nmspace.dto.ConfigJsonObj
```

I have no idea why I am getting no class def found error!

Comment: Rebuild your project, make sure all dependencies are present. I don't think this is a Gson issue.

Comment: did that, same result.. All these classes are present in same package. Both the above ConfigJson* classes were inner classes earlier, now I have moved them into their separate files.

Comment: I really, really don't think this is a Gson issue. It's *something* related to your build or project setup, that's what causes `NoClassDefFoundError`. However, this question doesn't have enough information for us to help you figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it working now, after 2 evenings spent with this error!

I was using the Gson serializing / deserializing code inside another class which was a ParseObject and it gave me the errors.

Eg.

```
@ParseClassName("MyParseObject")
public class MyParseObject extends ParseObject {

public void setConfigJsonObj(ConfigJsonObject configJsonObj) {
   String json = (new Gson).toJson(configJsonObj);
   put("config_json",json);
}
public ConfigJsonObject getConfigJsonObject() {
   String config_json = getString("config_json");
   ConfigJsonObject obj = (new Gson).fromJson(config_json,ConfigJsonObject.class);
   return obj;

 }

}
```

I wanted to encapsulate the object <-> json conversion into the dto class, but it cannot be done in this case.

So now I have replaced the above code and made serialization / deserialization external to MyParseObject class and I pass json directly to it, rather than the custom object.

Hope that also helps someone else.
Cheers